# has_many through relation in active model serializers Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, serialization, active-model-serializers

I have many to many relation between `users` and `projects` through `user_project`. I know I could simply add `has_many :projects` in User Serializer (and vice versa in project serializer) to nest projects inside users.

But I also have a few additional fields in `user_projects` table (eg. start and end dates for user's participation in a corresponding project) and I have no idea what is the correct way to include them in the returned json. Should I create a special serializer for projects that are returned inside user with `start_date` included as a project's attribute or there's another way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to establish a `'has-many-through'` (HMT) relationship between the `user` and `project` models and create a serializer for relationship's model.

```
class UserProjectSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  ...
end
```

This will then be used in the `UserSerializer` via:

```
has_many :users_projects
```

The reason is that the relationship between the models contains additional data.

To implement the HMT, you'll need to create the `user_projects` model and define the HMT relationship in the related models:

**users_project.rb**

```
class UserProjects < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: users_projects
  has_many: projects, through: :user_projects
end
```

**project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: users_projects
  has_many: users, through: :user_projects
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem before and I made use of [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl).  There is a good tutorial on [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl) to help you get started.